# spec helper doesn't access default_url_options in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

We overwrite restful methods in a helper and wanna test them.
Everything works great except that the `default_url_options` is not used from the ApplicationController. This problem occours only when I run the tests.

We actually managed to fix it by stubbing ActionController::Base like this

```
ActionController::Base.stub(:default_url_options).and_return :locale => locale || I18n.locale
```

It feels a bit hacky and I wonder if there is a better solution for it.

Comment: I'm working on this as well - it seems that some people have added the `default_url_options` method to a `TestController` class in order to make it visible to the tests. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255